# 'Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIImage *' from 'UIImageView *'? Help please

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiimageview, uiimage, xcode5

So I'm creating a camera app for my Multimedia Major and I've come across this error in my 'VSViewController.m' file;

```
self.image.image = _image;
```

"'Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIImage *' from 'UIImageView *'"

Any help is appreciated!

(BELOW IS THE BLOCK OF CODE IT WAS IN)

```
    #import "VSViewController.h"

@interface VSViewController ()

@end

@implementation VSViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Image Picker Delegate
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

self.image.image = _image.image;

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: that error says that self.image.image is a UIImage and the property _image is a UIImageView. It's like trying to assign an apple as an orange. Not much other information to be had.

Comment: As an aside... self.image.image = _image.image is a no-op.  self.image will assign to _image, if you're using default property synthesis.

Comment: Well, at least the code you've now posted will compile, but unless, as mentioned above, you are doing something fancy, all you have there is self.image.image = self.image.image. Since _image is the same as self.image. First step to starting down the road of less confusion is to change some of those property names. Second step is retracing the logic or the step you missed in the tutorial you are following.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code.

```
func test() {
    var image = UIImage(named: "default.png")   // UIImage

    var imageView = UIImageView()               // UIImageView

    image = imageView.image   // assigns image (UIImage) to imageView.image (UIImage)
}
```

You must assign a `UIImage` to your image, not a `UIImageView`. Use the `UIImageView`'s `image` property to get compatible pointer types.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so now that we know what you're doing it looks like you should be extracting the image out of the imagePicker's dictionary like so:

`self.image.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];`

That assumes that `self.image` is a `UIImageView`, but again I would recommend coming up with better names.

Comment: @user3739491 care to elaborate? If that didn't work, then you'll need to post some more code in your question.

Comment: I just added the block that the error is in to the main question!

Answer (score 0):

I came across two ways of solving this error after I got the same error from my first blind attempt.

One was to use the image property of my UIImageView's ivar/property, as Brian above mentioned. But when I did that, I found I had to constantly call this image property along with its UIImageView property/variable, as in I was calling: `self.UIImageViewiVar.image` rather than just `self.UIImageViewiVar`.

Another way to do it is via the `initWithImage:` method like so:

```
self.UIImageViewiVar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"XYZ.jpeg"]];
```

And thereafter you can just call on self.UIImageViewiVar.

Hope this helps someone.